# Powershell / .net reflection - GetMethod() finds a normal method, but not a generic one - why?

Tags: powershell, reflection

Setup: on Windows 10 / PS 5.1, run this to get access to the WindowsRuntime and the WinRT types I'm using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
[Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction,Windows.Foundation,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
[Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1,Windows.Foundation,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
[Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperationWithProgress`2,Windows.Foundation,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
```

OK, now find an extension method I'm not looking for - `AsTask()` which takes one parameter, typed as an `[IAsyncAction]`:

```
[System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethod('AsTask', 
                                                  [Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction])
```

There will be some output - a method found.

---

Now try for the one I *am* looking for, the same `AsTask()` method, but this time the overload which takes a parameter typed `IAsyncOperation<T>` or [IAsyncOperation`1]:

```
[System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethod('AsTask', 
                                             [Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1])
```

No output. No output if the type name is given as a string instead.

But that overload *does* exist; ask for all the methods and filter them afterwards, and this will find it:

```
([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and 
               $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
```

This last block of code is what I am using and it works, the question which led me here was: can I ask for that method directly from [GetMethod()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) in one call?

Comment: `[Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction]` does not belong to `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` assembly, that is why it is not available after `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`. Tab completion likely touch something that trigger right assembly to be loaded and type become available.

Comment: And you get no methods because none of them accept open generic type ``[Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1]`` as argument. The method you are looking for is accepting ``[Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1]`` closed over method type parameter. You can retrieve that method with `GetMethod` call, but I do not know way how to do that, which do not require knowing target method already.

Comment: Can't you just use `[type] | Get-Member -MemberType Method -Static`?

Comment: @PetSerAl Of course, it's not in the right assembly, obvious now you point it out - thanks! I've edited the question with some working type loading code. I don't understand what you mean by "*closed over method type parameter*" - what I'm looking for eventually is `AsTask(IAsyncOperation<Windows.Media.Import.PhotoImportSource>)` if that matters

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler what they mean is the generic argument for the parameter type is *not* the generic parameter of the type.  It's the generic parameter of the *method*.  While they represent similar things, they are not equal. FWIW I've never been able to find a good way to do this, and typically resort to filtering results of `Type.GetMember(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

The types from the generic "AsTask"-method and [Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1] are not the same even if they have the same type-GUID. They are different in 4 parameters, but they are read-only:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$methods = [System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods()
$taskList = $methods | ?{$_.Name -eq "AsTask"}
$asTask = $taskList | ?{$_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' }

$type1 = $asTask.GetParameters().ParameterType
$type2 = [Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1]

$attribList = ("IsGenericTypeDefinition", "IsConstructedGenericType", "GenericTypeParameters", "GenericTypeArguments")
foreach ($attrib in $attribList) {
    "$attrib : $($type1.$attrib) -> $($type2.$attrib)"
}
```